# Passing array of id's into function throwing error

Tags: jquery

I have a multiple tables (more than 10) which are dynamically generated and each row as a delete button with a unique id. What I am trying to achieve is when a user clicks on any of the delete buttons to get the id of the delete button and delete that row. I know I can do

```
$('#first-item-table, #second-item-table').on('click', '.delete-attachment', function () {
   row = $(this).closest("tr"),
   id = $(this).attr("id");

   //post to server & delete record from db and on success remove the row
   row.Remove();
});
```

Now this works as expected but when I pass in all the table names into `$('#first-item-table, #second-item-table')` it gets difficult to read. So I thought I would create an array as

```
const tableIds = ['#first-item-table','#first-item-table'...];
```

Now if I pass in `tableIds` I get the following error:

> Object.defineProperty called on non-object

Can someone tell me how to pass in my table id into the function please.

Comment: tableIds[0] like that. you should use the index of the array item

Comment: why not give your tables a `class` attribute, then use that `class` name in jquery selector? :/ like just `$('.table-action').on('click',...`

Comment: yeah u can do so as taufik says